# sql query to get users data in one row

Tags: sql, codeigniter

```
username  skill      mark

x          writing   10
x          reading   11

a          writing   15
a         reading    14
```

i want to get an o/p like this:

```
x       10   11
y       15  14
```

Comment: You should probably read this first [How to ask ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then you can rewrite your question, show what you tried, and tag the proper RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation is the way to go:

```
SELECT t.username,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.skill = 'writing' THEN t.mark END) as writing_mark,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.skill = 'reading' THEN t.mark END) as reading_mark
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select username,skill,mark from Your_table;#this fetches only 3

Or 

select * from Your_table; #this will fetch all fields of your table
```

Comment: I think the table has 3 cols so you have to join them on the username if I understand the op correctly.

Comment: Are those fields from different tables? I am not clear with the question

Comment: these r from same table only